# CMake conan. how to change selected parameter out of default settings

Tags: cmake, conan

I'm using Conan from cmake, and prior to `Conan install` I extract the default settings using this command :

```
conan_cmake_autodetect(settings)
```

after this line the output of settings is as follows :

```
build_type=Debugcompiler=apple-clangcompiler.version=13.1compiler.libcxx=libc++
```

I'd like to change the compiler.version from 13.1 to 13.

what is the best way to do so (I'd rather avoid modify the string value of settings directly.)

Thanks !

Comment: The `conan_cmake_autodetect` collects the information directly from CMake. You need to use a profile instead. https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan#profile

Comment: @uilianries, thanks for the insight. I'd like to overrun only the compiler version and leave the other settings untouched. is there a way to mix between profile and settings, so that only the compiler version will be taken from the profile ?

Comment: Unfortunately not.